# Including Fake-headers via pycparser in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pycparser

We can support new typedefs , #includes and #defines , by preprocessing it with the help of pycparser parse_file . I also went through the documentation:  README page and the blog post , but all the documentation was written for linux systems.I have no clue about linux systems and would love to get the documentation for windows.

Comment: Perhaps raise this issue with the devs of pycparser. We can't really write documentation for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is one and the same. You cannot effectively use pycparser without a basic understanding of how the C compilation pipeline works - sorry!

The documentation actually addresses Windows directly. The only difference is that instead of relying on a system C compiler (on Linux) you have to explicitly download one for Windows - and the documentation even gives you a link. Once you download Clang for Windows, which gives you preprocessing on Windows, everything else is platform-agnostic.